# For security compliance ,create Azure policy for key vault where access should be granted to AD groups only, not Individual users

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-policy

Create Azure policy for key vault where access should be granted to AD groups, MSIs and SPNs. Individual users must not have access. Reader role should be assigned to protect key access. What will be the content of policyRule block?

Answer (score 0):

Policy is not user-aware so this will not be possible. This would have to be solved using RBAC.